# How to make new Xcode 4.x schemes shared by default?

Tags: xcode4

I generally always want my Xcode 4.x schemes to be shared. And yet, new ones default to be per-user. Does anyone know a way to change this default to shared?

**NB**: I know how to make an *existing* scheme shared (cf. [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH9-SW26)).

Comment: Did you got the answer? I am making xcode templates and I want the scheme to be shared by default. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Radio silence so far.

Comment: I think this default has changed. Schemes are shared by default now.